# Проблема синхронизации локального репозитория и git-репозитория

Tags: git

Есть проект, идентичный на локалке и на git.
Хочу их связать.
Делаю:
`git remote add origin <>`
`git push -all origin`
Все успешно, но `git status` выдает

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        //содержимое локальной папки

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

В чем может быть проблема?
Уже проделал: удалить `.git`, заново `git init` - не помогло.
`git clone <> .` ругается, что папка уже существует и не пустая.

Comment: поменяй название папки, когда делаешь клон то `git` сам создает папку с именем удаленного рапозитория.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan дело в том, что на локалке лежали файлы, которые я не коммитил (картинки). Их тогда вручную перенести в новый (чистый) репозиторий?

Comment: перенесли на сервер да? на другой репозиторий в сервере? и ты хочешь скачать проект из нового репозитория ?

Comment: Перенести на локалке из одного проекта в другой.

Comment: ты как то путаешь все, дай подробный вопрос что ты сделал и после чего возникла проблема. В вопросе нечего не сказано про двух проектов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала необходимо посмотреть находишься ли в master.

```
git branch
```

если нет, то делаешь

```
git fetch
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

**P.S.** Один из самых простых вариантов это создать пустую папку сделать  в неё `git clone ...`
а потом перенести в рабочий каталог папку .git и .gitignore

Comment: `git branch` ведь должен что-то вернуть? у меня ничего не возвращает

Comment: @Tarasovych а ты находишься в той папке где у тебя проект?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan да

Comment: @Tarasovych если ты проект сделал с `git clone` то хоть `master branch`  у тебя должно быть.

Comment: git branch должен вернуть http://prntscr.com/fmba0w наподобии такого. Это список веток

Comment: Скорее всего нет локальной master ветки. Её надо сначало получить (git fetch). А потом переключиться на неё git checkout master

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan я сейчас говорю о "старом" проекте. Некоторое время назад я его запушил и не трогал. Видимо, слетели настройки гита. Я хотел связать этот проект с тем, что на гите. Без `clone`. Но видимо, проще сделать `clone` в чистую папку и перенести файлы из `.gitignore`

Comment: @Tarasovych Вообще да так проще.